# Java - Custom type nested in class

Tags: java, class, inner-classes, custom-type

I am once again asking for technical support.

I need to define a custom type inside a class, I've done it like this:

```
public class MainClass {
    private class CustomType {
        public byte[] varA;
        public int varB;

        public CustomType() {
            varA = new byte[3];   
            varB = 13;
        }
    }

    private CustomType[] myArray;


    public MainClass() {
        myArray = new CustomType[1024]
        System.out.println(this.CustomType[0].varB);
    }
}
```

When I run it throws a `NullPointerException` at `System.out.println(this.CustomType[0].varB);`

I've tested if myArray gets properly initialized with 1024 elements and it does, however I can't seem to access them.

I just moved from C++ to Java so I'm still getting used to it, am I missing something blatant?.

Comment: In Java primitives default to 0, boolean defaults to false, everything else defaults to null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things,

- You must instantiate CustomType.
- CustomType does not need access to `MainClass.this` so you can make it static.

So

```
public class MainClass {
    private static class CustomType {
        public byte[] varA;
        public int varB;

        public CustomType() {
            varA = new byte[3];   
            varB = 13;
        }
    }

    private CustomType[] myArray;


    public MainClass() {
        myArray = new CustomType[1024];
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i) {
            this.CustomType[i] = new CustomType();
        }
        // Or
        Arrays.setAll(myArray, CustomType::new);
        System.out.println(this.CustomType[0].varB);
    }
}
```

Not making it static stores a `MainClass.this` in every `CustomType` instance which is unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @Jens thanks, corrected the copy error. And added the setAll, though maybe too advanced immediately after a C++ to java switch.

Answer (score 2):

You only create an array without any objects, so this.CustomType[0] is null.

You should add the objects to the array:

```
public MainClass() {
    myArray = new CustomType[1024]
    for (int i =0; i<myArray.length;i++ {
      myArray[i] = new CustomType();
    }
    System.out.println(this.myArray[0].varB);
}
```

Also you should make the member of `CustomType` private and access it via getter and setter.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in java are objects. The following line of the code you posted creates an array of 1024 elements where each and every element is null.

```java
myArray = new CustomType[1024];
```

If you want to place actual objects in the array, named `myArray`, you need to create instances of class `CustomType` and assign them to elements of the array, for example:

```java
CustomType instance = new CustomType();
myArray[0] = instance;
```

Then you can execute the following line of code and it will not throw `NullPointerException`.

```java
System.out.println(myArray[0].varB);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the full code to get the value of `varB`. In which you can avoid declaring `CustomType[] myArray`

```
public class Test 
{
    private static class CustomType 
    {
        public byte[] varA;
        public int varB;

        public CustomType() {
            varA = new byte[3];   
            varB = 13;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String... args) 
    {       
        System.out.println(new CustomType().varB);
    }
}
```

Comment: There will be a reason why op intrduced that array

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to add some elements to that array. See the below steps for more information.

1. constructor will be invoked, when you create the object of that class
2. And then you created an empty array of CustomType with size 1024 and trying to access the first element which does not exist(default is null) and trying to perform operations on that null reference. So you are getting the NullPointerException.